# How can i defer a many to many field from object?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-queryset, deferred

Im trying to defer a field from my model, but .defer() seems not working.

Im running Django 1.9 with python 2.7.

(example code, simplified)

---

### models.py

```py
class MyModelA(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='test/')


class MyModelB(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
    defer_this = models.ManyToManyField(MyModelA, blank=True)
```

---

### views.py

```py
query =  MyModelB.objects.defer('defer_this')

for i in query:
    print i.title, i.defer_this.all()
```

---

And it prints defer_this objects.

Could somebody explain me how it works/why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

According to docs

> If you are using the results of a queryset in some situation where you
>   don’t know if you need those particular fields when you initially
>   fetch the data, you can tell Django not to retrieve them from the
>   database.
>
> This is done by passing the names of the fields to not load to defer()
>
> A queryset that has deferred fields will still return model instances.
>   Each deferred field will be retrieved from the database if you access
>   that field (one at a time, not all the deferred fields at once)

It means defer does not stop you from accessing the attribute you pass to `defer`. It will just not fetch it from database. When you (try to) access deferred attribute. It will fetch it from db then.

And in case of M2M fields, they are by default (kind of) deferred. When you query a model containing M2M field, django will not make join and get data from related tables. You have to explicitly tell django using `prefetch_related` and `selected_related` to make join and fetch related data.